# MS Graph API to access SPO with Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to automate one task in Office 365 by using powershell and for this I registered an app in AAD (V2 endpoint https://apps.dev.microsoft.com) and given access to MS Graph API with permissions "Have full access to all site collections", "Read and Write all groups" (and so on) access to the app.
I am able to get the O365 group details via below PnP powershell commands but I am not sure how to get the context of SharePoint site or how to connect to a SP site within the same PS script by utilizing the same App credentials.

```
Connect-PnPOnline -AppId '<App Id>' -AppSecret '<App Secret>' -AADDomain 'tenant.onmicrosoft.com'
$group = Get-PnPUnifiedGroup -Identity 'hello team'
$spSiteUrl = $group.SiteUrl
```

Any tips how can I connect to SPO site?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to access SharePoint site with Azure AD Oauth but getting access denied.

Sample code like:

```
$connection=Connect-PnPOnline -Url 'https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Developer' -AppId 'GUID' -AppSecret 'secret' -ReturnConnection 

#Get-PnPUnifiedGroup

Get-PnPSite
```

Then, i did research found this seems a known case.

https://www.o365recipes.com/retrieve-data-from-sharepoint-online-without-user-interaction/

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Developer/PnP-PowerShell-Connect-PnPOnline-using-AppId-gives-Access-denied/td-p/140958

So, you could try to register a SharePoint add-in and use add-in only policy for this case(the first thread).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I am aware of the method mentioned in first link and thats the standard way of creating the app credential in SPO but I was expecting that if I can use the same app principal for which i have given access to MS Graph API and SPO sites. Is it so that i have to create two app principals then?